# Similar? Similarly? which should I use here

Tags: grammar

I am having a hard time trying to write this correctly.

"As for procedure A, the controller handles it *similar* as with procedure B by using function C"

I suppose you understand what I want to say. That the controller handles procedure A and procedure B in a similar way.

But I suspect my grammar is wrong.

Comment: How something is handled=adverb=similarly or in a similar way [adjective + noun]

Answer (score 1):

You need an adverb to define the way *verb* is happening. So, it should be *similarly.*

You should have looked in [the dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/similarly) for the same though.

Nevertheless, later, you have used *'in a **similar** way'* correctly!

Comment: so, I should say ""As for procedure A, the controller handles it similarLY as with procedure B by using function C"?

Comment: "Similar" and "similarly" usually take the preposition "**to**". Procedure A and procedure B are **similar**. They are **similar to** each other. Procedure A is **similar to** procedure B. ..."As for procedure A, the controller handles it **similarly to** procedure B by using function C", *or even*: "Similarly to how it handles procedure B, the controller handles procedure A by using function C". There are other possibilities as well, but that's a few.